Can't set up FCM
I always got two errors when trying to set FCM up
My project - React + Vite
vite.config.ts
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import { sentryVitePlugin } from '@sentry/vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import md, { Mode } from 'vite-plugin-markdown';


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  publicDir: 'public/',

  resolve:{
    alias:{
      '@shared': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared'),
      '@modules': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/modules'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
    },
  },

  plugins: [svgr(), md({ mode: [Mode.REACT] }), react(), splitVendorChunkPlugin(), eslint(), sentryVitePlugin({
    org: 'cvt-sp-z-o-o',
    project: 'thr-react',
  })],

  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },

  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },

  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
});

package.json
"dependencies": {
"@byteowls/capacitor-sms": "5.0.0",
"@capacitor-community/contacts": "5.0.5",
"@capacitor-community/fcm": "6.0.0",
"@capacitor-firebase/authentication": "6.0.0",
"@capacitor/android": "6.1.0",
"@capacitor/app": "6.0.0",
"@capacitor/browser": "6.0.1",
"@capacitor/core": "6.1.0",
"@capacitor/geolocation": "6.0.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "6.1.0",
"@capacitor/keyboard": "6.0.1",
"@capacitor/push-notifications": "6.0.1",
"@capacitor/share": "6.0.1",
"@capawesome/capacitor-badge": "6.0.0",
"@emotion/react": "11.11.3",
"@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
"@hotjar/browser": "1.0.9",
"@mui/icons-material": "5.16.5",
"@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.122",
"@mui/material": "5.11.12",
"@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "7.11.1",
"@sandstreamdev/react-swipeable-list": "^1.0.2",
"@sentry/react": "7.102.0",
"@sentry/vite-plugin": "2.16.1",
"@talkjs/react": "0.1.7",
"@tanstack/react-query": "4.26.1",
"@tanstack/react-virtual": "3.0.1",
"@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.30",
"@types/google-map-react": "2.1.7",
"axios": "1.3.4",
"capacitor-native-settings": "6.0.0",
"capacitor-plugin-app-tracking-transparency": "2.0.5",
"chalk": "4.1.2",
"clear": "0.1.0",
"date-fns": "2.29.3",
"date-fns-tz": "2.0.1",
"figlet": "1.5.2",
"firebase": "9.17.2",
"geojson": "0.5.0",
"google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.34",
"google-map-react": "2.2.1",
"inquirer": "8.0.0",
"jsdom": "21.1.1",
"lodash": "4.17.21",
"query-string": "8.1.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-device-detect": "2.2.3",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-facebook-pixel": "1.0.4",
"react-firebase-hooks": "5.1.1",
"react-hook-form": "7.43.5",
"react-international-phone": "^4.2.9",
"react-markdown": "9.0.1",
"react-qr-code": "^2.0.15",
"react-router": "6.9.0",
"react-router-dom": "6.9.0",
"react-spinners": "0.13.8",
"react-text-loop": "^2.3.0",
"react-use": "17.4.0",
"rimraf": "4.4.0",
"sanitize-html": "2.10.0",
"supercluster": "8.0.1",
"talkjs": "0.18.0",
"use-supercluster": "1.1.0",
"web-vitals": "3.3.0"
},
"scripts": {
"dev": "vite --host",
"build": "tsc && vite build",
"preview": "vite preview",
"test": "vitest",
"coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ./src",
"lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ./src",
"ts": "tsc -p ./tsconfig.json",
"sync": "npx cap sync"
},
firebaseClient.ts
import { initializeApp, FirebaseOptions } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithRedirect,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithCustomToken,
  signOut,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  AuthProvider,
  OAuthProvider,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  TwitterAuthProvider,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
  initializeAuth,
  indexedDBLocalPersistence,
  signInWithCredential,
  updateProfile,
  signInWithPhoneNumber,
  linkWithPhoneNumber,
  updatePhoneNumber,
  PhoneAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging';
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@capacitor-firebase/authentication';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_DB_URL,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
export const isNative = () => Capacitor.isNativePlatform();

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

if (!isNative()) {
  const messaging = getMessaging(app);
  const getFCMToken = async () => {
    return Notification.requestPermission()
      .then(async (permission) => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
          console.log(getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY }));
        }
        if (permission === 'denied') {
          console.log('Notification permission denied.');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error getting FCM token', error);
      });
  };
  console.log('getFCMToken', await getFCMToken());
}



Error:
with this public/firebase-messaging-sw.js

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging/sw';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'apiKey',
  authDomain: 'authDomain',
  databaseURL: 'databaseURL',
  projectId: 'projectId',
  storageBucket: 'tstorageBucket',
  messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId',
  appId: 'appId7',
  measurementId: 'measurementId',
});

const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

Error:
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (registerDefaultSw.ts:43:25)
    at async updateSwReg (updateSwReg.ts:28:5)
    at async getToken$1 (getToken.ts:43:3)


Error:
error with this public/firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'apiKey',
  authDomain: 'authDomain',
  databaseURL: 'databaseURL',
  projectId: 'projectId',
  storageBucket: 'tstorageBucket',
  messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId',
  appId: 'appId7',
  measurementId: 'measurementId',
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

Error:
FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. (messaging/token-subscribe-failed).
    at requestGetToken (requests.ts:67:25)
    at async getNewToken (token-manager.ts:139:17)


You should use a Capacitor plugin for that (e.g. Capacitor Firebase Cloud Messaging) as not all Web APIs are available in the WebViews. A few months ago, I published a guide that explains every step in detail: https://capawesome.io/blog/the-push-notifications-guide-for-capacitor/

I need it for browsers on phone - not for installed apps

The guide also covers a web section.

I'm still having error
FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. (messaging/token-subscribe-failed).

if (!isNative()) {
const getFCMToken = async () => {
const options: GetTokenOptions = {
vapidKey: import.meta.env.VITE__CVT_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY,
};
options.serviceWorkerRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js');
const { token } = await FirebaseMessaging.getToken(options);

return token;

};
console.log('getFCMToken', await getFCMToken());
}
